# How are Python2's built-in reduce and functools.reduce different?

Tags: python, python-2.x, functools

Both have exact same documentation, and it seems to me that both stem from same source code in https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c.

However, I am not sure about it. I didn't find any other refernces in the source code of CPython. Can some one shed some more light on this here?

Comment: For one, it appears that Python 3 dropped support for `reduce()` without using `functools`.

Comment: `>>> import functools; functools.reduce` outputs `<built-in function reduce>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [the documentation of `functools.reduce` in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

> This is the same function as [reduce()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). It is made available in this
>   module to allow writing code more forward-compatible with Python 3.